# Change tootip title ng-highcharts

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

Hello i have implemented in my webApp `ng-highcharts` , but now i would change tooltip title if pass with mouse on section of chart.
I have this configuration for example:

```
options: {
   chart: {
      type: 'pie',
      defaultSeriesType: 'areaspline'
   },
   plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        depth: 25
      }
   }
 },
 series: [
    {
       name:'Durata interventi',
       data:[
          ['foo', 1],
          ['foo1', 2]]

       }],
       title:{
          text:"series"
       },
       loading: false,
       func: function(chart) {
          $timeout(function() {
             chart.reflow();

          }, 0);
       }
```

and it work, it show pie chart, with correct data, but if I pass the mouse over a section it print on tooltip a correct series name and in this case "foo" or "foo1", and my question is, can I set a different title for tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tooltip header can be changed via [tooltip.headerFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.tooltip.headerFormat). A complete control over a tooltip can be achieved with a [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) callback.

```
 tooltip: {
          headerFormat: 'custom header<br>',

        /*formatter: function () {
            var a = 2 + 2;
            return 'do what you want ' + a;
          }*/
        }
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/m4pcpv5g/209/